# How to list all dates in a period that match one or more weekdays

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I want to list all dates that match one or more weekdays of specified period (start date to end date). Weekdays are listed as numerical values (MON=1...FRI=5), and there can be from one to five weekdays/digits listed (eg. 3 = WED, 12 = MON & TUE, 345 = WED & THU & FRI, etc).

The code should compare the first weekday/digit to the start date, and either list a matching date into a separate column or jump to the next weekday/digit and repeat the comparison. When there is a match, or if all listed weekdays/digits have been cycled through unsuccessfully, the start date should be updated to the next day & the process repeated until the whole period is checked.

My code works for the first weekday/digit listed, but I am unable to get it to jump to the next weekday/digit, ie. if weekdays/digits listed are 12345 (MON to FRI), I get only those dates that correspond to the first weekday/digit (MON). 
Select case works, but requires that the number of weekdays/digits is always the same.
I tried to place the counter that updates start dates and the position of the weekday/digit into different places of the loop, but it either gives results only for the first weekday/digit or results in overflow.

```
Sub CollectionDaysTrialV02()

Dim PeriodStartDate, PeriodEndDate As Date
Dim CollectionDays As Range
Dim cycle, rw, iLength, iDigit As Integer

PeriodStartDate = Range("b1").Value
PeriodEndDate = Range("b2").Value
Set CollectionDays = Range("d6")
cycle = 0
iDigit = Mid(CollectionDays, cycle + 1, 1)
iLength = Len(CollectionDays.Value)
rw = 2
        Do
            If Weekday(PeriodStartDate, vbMonday) <> iDigit Then
                cycle = cycle + 1
            Else
                Cells(rw, 6).Value = PeriodStartDate
                Cells(rw, 6).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
                rw = rw + 1
                cycle = cycle + 1
            End If
                PeriodStartDate = PeriodStartDate + 1
        Loop Until PeriodStartDate = PeriodEndDate

End Sub

Sub Init()
    Range("B1") = "01/07/19"
    Range("B2") = "01/11/19"

    Range("D6") = "12345"
End Sub
```

For the period 01/07/19 - 01/11/19, and weekdays MON-FRI (12345), the result should be 01/07/19, 01/08/19, 01/09/19, 01/10/19, 01/11/19. So far the result is only 01/07/19.

Added:

Period start/end days are manually entered on the worksheet, the weekdays and some other data is retrieved via a couple of Vlookup formulas. The weekdays are actually supplier collection days - my purpose is first to list all possible scheduled collection days for a time period, then check if any of these weekdays falls on a bank holiday in the supplier country. A last step will be to check if any of the listed collection days + the predefined transit time creates a conflict by falling onto a bank holiday in the country of delivery. I tried to add a link to the the image of the Excel worksheet for clarification:

[CollectionSchedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhxPe.jpg)

The dates listed in the linked image are the result of running the code of simple-solution (without the sub init). I do not actually need the weekday values and the weekdays in columns G:H, but I left them for clarification. All the requested dates are now listed, but the order is based on the weekdays (ie MON, MON, TUE, TUE, etc). I could already work with this solution, either by sorting the dates in the worksheet table or in VBA, but as this problem has occupied me for several days I would really like to know if there is a way to loop through this according to my initial description (first start date against first weekday, second weekday, etc until there is a match or all weekdays have bee looped through, and only then jumping to the next start date in line), so that the result would be displayed MON, TUE, WED...MON, TUE, WED, in chronological order.

Comment: Why don't you update your code with a Sub Init, which gives us all the values we need to test your code? e.g. Range("B1") = "01/07/19" ...

Comment: How does the CollectionDays look like? I edited your code to include a sub init ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub Init()
    Range("B1") = "01/07/19"
    Range("B2") = "01/17/19"

    Range("D6") = "1245"
End Sub

Sub CollectionDaysTrialV03()

Dim PeriodStartDate As Date
Dim PeriodEndDate As Date
Dim ActualDate As Date
Dim CollectionDays As Range
Dim cycle As Integer
Dim rw As Integer
Dim iLength As Integer
Dim iDigit As Integer
Dim iCt As Integer

PeriodStartDate = Range("b1").Value
PeriodEndDate = Range("b2").Value
Set CollectionDays = Range("d6")

'Clear Result
Range("F1:E10").ClearContents

cycle = 0
iDigit = Mid(CollectionDays, cycle + 1, 1)
iLength = Len(CollectionDays.Value)
rw = 2

    For ActualDate = PeriodStartDate To PeriodEndDate
        For iCt = 1 To iLength
            iDigit = Mid(CollectionDays, iCt, 1)
            Debug.Print "iDigit: "; iDigit
            'ActualDate = PeriodStartDate
            If Weekday(ActualDate, vbMonday) = iDigit Then
                    Cells(rw, 6).Value = ActualDate
                    Cells(rw, 6).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
                    Cells(rw, 7).Value = iDigit
                    Cells(rw, 7).Value = iDigit
                    Cells(rw, 8).Value = ActualDate
                    Cells(rw, 8).NumberFormat = "dddd"
                    rw = rw + 1
                    'cycle = cycle + 1
            End If
            'ActualDate = ActualDate + 1
            'Loop Until ActualDate = PeriodEndDate + 1
        Next iCt
    Next ActualDate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub Init()
Range("B1") = "01/07/19"
Range("B2") = "01/11/19"
Range("D6") = "12345"
Range("F1:E100").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub CollectionDaysTrialV02()

Dim PeriodStartDate As Date
Dim PeriodEndDate As Date
Dim ActualDate As Date
Dim CollectionDays As Range
Dim cycle As Integer
Dim rw As Integer
Dim iLength As Integer
Dim iDigit As Integer
Dim iCt As Integer

PeriodStartDate = Range("b1").Value
PeriodEndDate = Range("b2").Value
Set CollectionDays = Range("d6")

'Clear Result
Range("F1:E10").ClearContents

cycle = 0
iDigit = Mid(CollectionDays, cycle + 1, 1)
iLength = Len(CollectionDays.Value)
rw = 2

    For iCt = 1 To iLength
        iDigit = Mid(CollectionDays, iCt, 1)
        Debug.Print "iDigit: "; iDigit
        ActualDate = PeriodStartDate
        Do
            If Weekday(ActualDate, vbMonday) = iDigit Then
                Cells(rw, 6).Value = ActualDate
                Cells(rw, 6).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
                Cells(rw, 7).Value = iDigit
                Cells(rw, 7).Value = iDigit
                Cells(rw, 8).Value = ActualDate
                Cells(rw, 8).NumberFormat = "dddd"
                rw = rw + 1
                'cycle = cycle + 1
            End If
                ActualDate = ActualDate + 1
        Loop Until ActualDate = PeriodEndDate + 1
    Next iCt
End Sub
```

Comment: Period start/end days B1; B2, as well as the collection days D6 come via a vlookup function, so there is no need to define them separately. With your code all the requested weekdays within the period are now displayed, albeit not chronologically but all MONs first, then all TUEs, etc. It´s a big step ahead, and as the dates are displayed into table I could just sort them, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this via VBA.